# Hausdorff Dimension Question

Tags: real-analysis

My question is basically,

Let $A_r$ be the set of numbers $x \in [0,1]$ s.t. the inequality $|x-\sqrt{\frac{p}{q}}| < \frac{1}{q^r}$, where $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$, can be satisfied for infinitely many $q$. Then prove $m(A_r)=0$ for $r>2$, and that the Hausdorff dimension of $A_r$ is at most $2/r$. How do I go about proving this?

Comment: Is this a homework?

Comment: Instead of asking here, you could look up "Jarnik's Theorem" in a textbook.

Comment: Ah, is there any online resource available? I tried googling but the results were rather convoluted and confusing

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For a given positive integer $q$ those $x \in [0,1]$ such that $|x - \sqrt{p/q}| < 1/q^r$ for some $p$
are in the union of a certain number of intervals, each of a certain length.  Can you bound the sum of the lengths of these intervals?  What about the sum of the $d$'th powers of the lengths?